# Google invisible reCaptcha is only working in Incognito mode

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, grecaptcha

I have a Google reCAPTCHA setup on my contact form in my website.

and i'm trying to test it in both localhost and server as well but recaptcha is only working in incognito mode .

without capturing reCAPTCHA mails are sending  .
Here my problem is grecaptcha.execute(); is not executing, Please suggest solution for this.

```js
$("#cont_msg").keypress(function (e) {
    var key = e.which;
    if (key == 13) {
      // the enter key code
      $("#contact_form_submit").click();
      return false;
    }
  });

  $(
    ".app_form_wrapper .apps_input input, .app_form_wrapper .apps_input textarea"
  ).keypress(function () {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("error");
  });
  
  function sendMail() {
  var co_name = $("#cont_name").val();
  var co_email = $("#cont_email").val();
  var co_phone = $("#cont_phone").val();
  var co_company = $("#cont_company").val();
  var co_message = $("#cont_msg").val();
  let data = {
    username: co_name,
    useremail: co_email,
    userphone: co_phone,
    usercompany: co_company,
    usermessage: co_message,
  };
  $("#loading").show();
  $("#contact_form_submit").hide();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contact_ajaxmail.php",
    data: data,
    success: function (contact) {
      //grecaptcha.execute();
      $("#loading").hide();
      $("#contact_form_submit").show();

      var i = contact.split("#");
      if (i[0] == "1") {
        $("#cont_name").val("");
        $("#cont_email").val("");
        $("#cont_phone").val("");
        $("#cont_company").val("");
        $("#cont_msg").val("");
        $("#contact_err").html(i[1]);

        $(".app_form_wrapper .apps_input").addClass("success");
        setTimeout(function () {
          $(".app_form_wrapper .apps_input").removeClass("success");
          $(".app_form_wrapper .apps_input").removeClass("error");
          $("#cont_email").parent().removeClass("error");
        }, 2500);
      } else {
        $("#cont_name").val(data.username);
        $("#cont_email").val(data.useremail);
        $("#cont_phone").val(data.userphone);
        $("#cont_company").val(data.usercompany);
        $("#cont_msg").val(data.usermessage);
        $("#contact_err").html(i[1]);

        $(
          ".app_form_wrapper .apps_input input, .app_form_wrapper .apps_input textarea"
        ).each(function () {
          if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).parent().addClass("error");
          } else {
            if (i[0] == 3) {
              $("#cont_email").parent().addClass("error");
            } else {
              $(this).parent().addClass("error");
            }
            $(this).parent().removeClass("error");
          }
        });
      }
    },
  });
}

**My form**
Here iam trying to send mails for entered email
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <!-- BEGIN HEAD -->
    <head>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>

    </head>
<form class="app_form_wrapper" role="form" >
                <div class="col-lg-6 text-left">
                    <div class="form-group apps-pulldown-20">
                        <div class="apps_input">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cont_name"placeholder="Name">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group apps-pulldown-20">
                        <div class="apps_input">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cont_email" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group apps-pulldown-20">
                        <div class="apps_input">
                            <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="cont_phone" placeholder="Phone Number" minlength="10" maxlength="15">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                     <div class="form-group apps-pulldown-20">
                        <div class="apps_input">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cont_company" placeholder="Company">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group apps-pulldown-20">
                        <div class="apps_input">
                            <textarea rows="10" class="form-control" id="cont_msg" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="g-recaptcha"
                      data-sitekey="Site_key"
                      data-callback="sendMail"
                      data-size="invisible">
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        This site is protected by reCAPTCHA and the Google
                        <a href="https://policies.google.com/privacy">Privacy Policy</a> and
                        <a href="https://policies.google.com/terms">Terms of Service</a> apply.
                    </p>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg contact_btn" id="contact_form_submit">Send</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-default btn-lg contact_btn" id="loading" style="display: none;">Sending...</a>

                    <p class="input_error"id="contact_err" style="color:#FF6666;position:absolute;font-size:14px;font-weight: 500;letter-spacing: 0.5px;bottom: 10px;left: 0;right: 0;">
                </p>
                </div>
        </form>
        
        
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#contact_form_submit").on("click", function () {
    var co_name = $("#cont_name").val();
    var co_email = $("#cont_email").val();
    var co_phone = $("#cont_phone").val();
    var co_company = $("#cont_company").val();
    var co_message = $("#cont_msg").val();
    if (
      co_name != "" &&
      co_email != "" &&
      co_phone != "" &&
      co_company != "" &&
      co_message != ""
    ) {
      grecaptcha.execute();
    } else {
      $("#loading").hide();
      $("#contact_form_submit").show();
      $("#contact_err").html("Please fill all the fields !!!!");
    }
  });
    })   
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure that your script is not just cached in your _non incognito_ mode? Did you try to `console.log` anything to see that your script it being updated?

Comment: Are you providing any SERVER side validation in `contact_ajaxmail.php` ? Something along the lines of https://gist.github.com/adhershmnair/43bba7c1c58bce86e0a1fda77be47129

Comment: Hi @Rippo  i have not added server side validation in contact_ajaxmail.php file and i tried similar way which you sent  still getting same thing , can you please help me where can i do server side validation . https://bitbucket.org/harshithss98/demo/src/master/

Comment: Do you perhaps have an adblocker installed that is possibly blocking javascript? By default extensions are disabled in incognito.

Answer (score 0):

Captcha needs two things to make it work properly

1. Client side code in Javascript, this you have done by looks of it properly.
2. Server side code, without implementing server side code the captcha is **useless** as bots will just post straight to your PHP form without having to enter a captcha! This is your missing piece based on your comments.

See

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/intro

Notice it says you need to do 2 steps, 1 client side, 2 verify the response:

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Google returns loads results but this seems to be an up to date article

https://phppot.com/php/php-contact-form-with-google-recaptcha/

[Google implementing google captcha php](https://www.google.com/search?q=implementing%20google%20captcha%20php&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk00Efl5vCU1B9-uWR9YCsxT26cPyqw%3A1621496889657&ei=ORSmYOPGJ8-HjLsPy5KdmA0&oq=implementing%20google%20captcha%20php&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBggAEBYQHjoHCCMQsAMQJzoHCAAQRxCwA1CfCViiDmDbD2gBcAJ4AIABbIgBoAOSAQM0LjGYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6yAEJwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwijx_LQ4tfwAhXPA2MBHUtJB9MQ4dUDCA0&uact=5)